How to Externalize Configuration for Azure Functions (hosting.json)?
I have an Azure Function written in Java 17 using Spring Cloud Functions that processes data from Event Hub.  and I need to set the enqueueTime to a specific time (e.g., a few minutes earlier) whenever the service is stopped and restarted.
Currently, we manually set this value before starting the application. I'm looking for a way to externalize this configuration so the function can automatically pick it up from an external source, such as a configuration repository.
Is there a recommended approach for hosting and managing such external configurations for Azure Functions? Any insights or best practices would be appreciated. Thank you!

Can you share your code in the question?

Use Azure App Configuration to externalize enqueueTime and load it dynamically into the function using '@Value'. This centralizes management and avoids manual updates during restarts.
